# Create dynamic tables based on a loop in PostgreSQL 9.2

Tags: postgresql, function, plpgsql, dynamic-sql, postgresql-9.2

I have a function where I want to create a table for a every year based on the year from bill date which I will be looping.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ccdb.ccdb_archival()
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
DECLARE dpsql text;
DECLARE i smallint;
BEGIN

FOR i IN SELECT DISTINCT EXTRACT(year FROM bill_date) FROM ccdb.bills ORDER  BY 1 LOOP

DO $$ 
    BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ccdb_archival.bills||i (LIKE ccdb.bills INCLUDING ALL);
    BEGIN
        ALTER TABLE ccdb_archival.bills ADD COLUMN archival_date timestamp;
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN duplicate_column THEN RAISE NOTICE 'column archival_date already exists in <table_name>.';
    END;
    END;
$$; 

INSERT INTO ccdb_archival.bills
SELECT *, now() AS archival_date
FROM ccdb.bills
WHERE bill_date::date >= current_date - interval '3 years' AND bill_date::date < current_date - interval '8 years';
END LOOP;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

I want to concatenate the year with the actual table name for each year.
I am unable to do the same with the above code. I get an error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "||"
LINE 3:   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ccdb_archival.bills||i (LI...
```

Please suggest how do I achieve my requirement.

Comment: You need dynamic SQL: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN

Comment: Thanks.... Got the desired result using Dynamic SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot compose strings with metadata. You should utilize execute: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ecpg-sql-execute-immediate.html

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11549128)

Comment: It is an answer supported from facts. The critiques are about the sex of the angels, what does Picasso means with his paint and so on. But in the science there is facts. So if he makes such question the answer is the above.

Comment: It would have been better if you _showed_ him how to use it (which is what answers are for) rather than only likning him to a site. Your answer was flagged for review, so I reviewed it.

Answer (score 0):

To create N tables with a prefix use this script.
This code uses a for loop and variable to creates 10 table starting with prefix 'sbtest' namely sbtest1, sbtest2 ... sbtest10

create_table.sql

```
do $$
    DECLARE myvar integer;
begin
    for myvar in 1..10 loop
        EXECUTE format('CREATE TABLE sbtest%s (
        id SERIAL NOT NULL,
        k INTEGER NOT NULL,
        c CHAR(120) NOT NULL,
        pad CHAR(60) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (id))', myvar);
    end loop;
end; $$
```

Run it using psql -U user_name -d database_name -f create_table.sql

```
Example Table  sbtest1 is as
id | k | c | pad
----+---+---+-----
(0 rows)

Table "public.sbtest1"
 Column |      Type      | Collation | Nullable |               Default               | Storage  | Stats
 target | Description
--------+----------------+-----------+----------+-------------------------------------+----------+------
--------+-------------
 id     | integer        |           | not null | nextval('sbtest1_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    |
        |
 k      | integer        |           | not null |                                     | plain    |
        |
 c      | character(120) |           | not null |                                     | extended |
        |
 pad    | character(60)  |           | not null |                                     | extended |
        |
Indexes:
    "sbtest1_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
Access method: heap
```